# Mouse over + click doesn't work only the very first time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox defined as :

```
<ListBox Margin="0,5,0,5" Visibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDNSList}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDNS}" Grid.Row="4" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseUp">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DNSListMouseUpCommand}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Margin="0,2" Background="Transparent">
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <!--Favorite-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
                            <!--Icon-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="75"/>
                            <!--Name-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                            <!--IPs-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>                                
                            <!--Trash-->
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>                            
                        <!--Favorite-->
                        <!--REMOVED HERE-->
                        <!--Image-->
                        <!--REMOVED HERE-->
                        <!--Name-->
                        <!--REMOVED HERE-->
                        <!--IPs-->
                        <!--REMOVED HERE-->
                        <!--Trash-->
                        <Image Grid.Column="6" Margin="0,0,10,0"  MaxWidth="32" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Source="/Assets/trash5.png">
                            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonUp">
                                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DataContext.TrashImgMouseLeftUpCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListBox}}}" PassEventArgsToCommand="True"/>
                                </i:EventTrigger>
                            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </Image>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

And corresponding Command functions are :

```
private void _TrashImgMouseLeftUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (SelectedDNS != null)
            {
                // 1) add the item to be removed to the "to be trashed" list                    
                // note : Force Add() if AddDNSItem() fail. We will deal with duplicate when closing the App.
                if (!DNSToTrashList.AddDNSItem(SelectedDNS))
                    DNSToTrashList.Add(SelectedDNS);
                TrashedDNSCount = _TrashedDNSCount();
                HaveTrashedDNS = _HaveTrashedDNS(false);
                //2) remove the trashed DNS of the ObservableCollection<DNSItem>
                MyDNSList.Remove(SelectedDNS);
            }
            e.Handled = true;                
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        { Console.WriteLine("No DNS selected, remove impossible\n" + ex.Message); }
    }

private void _DNSListMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickCount == 1 && Keyboard.Modifiers == ModifierKeys.Control)
        {
            CurrentDNS = SelectedDNS;
            return;
        }
        NewDNS_VM.Dns = SelectedDNS;
    }
```

The issue is right after I run the app (F5 in VS2019), and directly click on my "trash" icon button, the `TrashImgMouseLeftUpCommand` doesn't fire up but instead `DNSListMouseUpCommand`!

But after that initial first click it work as expected.
Also if I first maximize the window for example, it directly work as expected if I click on my "trash" icon.

Any clue on why event is messed up on very first interaction ?

**EDIT**
Ok i figured out why :
When the window open, my list box show my Items with a vertical scroll. When I click on the trash icon (or everything along this item actually), and before releasing my mouse left button (and without moving it), for a yet not understood reason, the list box items scroll up. This has the consequence to make my mouse cursor not being over the trash icon anymore, and so the MouseLeftButtonUp event doesn't trigger.

Now I have to understand why clicking on the list box's items make it scroll ???

Comment: Try using "PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" event on the trash image instead of "MouseLeftButtonUp"

Comment: @cmos tried PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp instead as you suggested, but without any success unfortunately.

Comment: Ok I know why it "bug", now I'll have to know how to resolve it. See my EDIT on OP.